# Using gitlab cicd to automatically merge branches

Tags: python, git, continuous-integration, gitlab

gitlab has this functionality that you can use pipelines that will execute code whenever you push code to your project.
this is done through their .gitlab-ci.yml file format

i am trying to somehow make the pipeline to merge all branches with prefix "ready/"
i have written a python program to do it locally, but it wont execute on the gitlab docker remote machine. this is due to the fact that it only lists "* and master" as branches with "git branch -a".

i have tried to checkout to master but that dosent work.

is this even possible on the gitlab pipeline? how would i go forward?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this depending what credentials you want to use, what you prefer, and what is better suited to your use case.

1. Use [SSH in CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/) (with SSH keys) to use your standard git commands to pull, do whatever, then push to the repo as part of a pipeline job.
2. Use the [merge requests API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html) which requires a [personal access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html). The API allows you to create, accept, and merge a merge request.

If you have a lot of branches, then you may want to use the first method.

Comment: I want this to happen automatically tho. the ssh option requires a outside computer to run the commands inside a ssh connection?. and dosent the api option require a merge request for all the branches?

Comment: If you take a look at the doc links, the one I link to is specifically on how to use SSH in CI/CD so that you can run whatever git commands you want in your script. I've edited my answer so that hopefully it's clearer. As to the MR option, yes, it does, which is why I noted that if you have a lot of branches, you're better off using the SSH method.